# Spell check for more than 1 languages in Android

Tags: gboard, spell-check

I try to make the spell check work for more than one language on my Pixel 2 (Android 8.1) with Gboard. My question is *not* about auto-correction or word prediction.

The spell check is activated and the two languages (UK and German) are activated in Language preferences and Gboard preferences. Changing the language while typing via the space bar does not solve the problem.

So far, it is only working in Google Docs:

[image: Language Setting]
[image: GBoard languages]
[image: SpellCheck Setting]
[image: Screenshot Google Docs]

I read the answers on [Stack Overflow - Adding a second dictionary to the spell-check in Android 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197421/adding-a-second-dictionary-to-the-spell-check-in-android-4-3), but they did not solve the problem.

I guess a solution for SwiftKey is even more difficult?

Comment: The fact that it's only working in google docs makes me think that this has nothing to do with the keyboard at all. Instead, I assume it has to do with the apps, which use the system language for their spellchecking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Gboard: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72386511

I tested flesky and SwiftKey and they do at least a spell check for one language.

Even if I only chose one system language and only one dedicated spell check language Gboard underlines nothing. In general this is the same for every App. Only Google Docs seems to have its own spell check.